# store_accessor method not found on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one model inherited from another, what has store attribute, sometimes, when I try to save child model, where are error :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `text' for #<Parent:0x00000007478ef0>)
```

My code:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :data
end

class Child < Parent
  store_accessor :data, :text
  validates :text, :presence => true
end
```

What is problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to define in Child class

```
class Child < Parent
  store :data, :text
  validates :text, :presence => true
end
```

and remove store definition from Parent class, there it has no sense at all.